# Cannot access the vertices pointer from GRAPH_global_context when using it on graph_generation.c

Tags: c, postgresql, apache-age

I'm working on a function for generating a Barabasi-Albert graph for AGE, and I'm having trouble getting any variables that the `GRAPH_global_context` structure has. I'm creating the function at `src/backend/utils/graph_generation.c` and I'm also including `"utils/age_global_graph.h"`.

I need to use this structure because some functions may help creating the Barabasi-Albert graph in a faster and more readable way and they use the `GRAPH_global_context` as parameter or at lest this structure contains a list or a variable that has to be passed as an argument. In this type of graph, where each new edge is added depends on how many other edges exists on each vertex, increasing the probability to add the new edge on them. Therefore, functions like the ones below may help finding which vertex has the most edges.

```c
ListGraphId *get_vertex_entry_edges_in(vertex_entry *ve);
ListGraphId *get_vertex_entry_edges_out(vertex_entry *ve);
ListGraphId *get_vertex_entry_edges_self(vertex_entry *ve);
```

I'm creating the GRAPH_global_context like this:

```c
/* The graph_name_str and graph_id are a pointer to char and an Oid. */
GRAPH_global_context* ggctx = manage_GRAPH_global_contexts(graph_name_str, graph_id);
```

But when I try to get the head of the `ggctx`'s `vertices` list, it shows an error:

```c
GraphIdNode* current_node = get_list_head(ggctx->vertices);
                                          ^
// pointer to incomplete class type "struct GRAPH_global_context" is not allowed
```

Comment: sounds like it doesn't know what `struct GRAPH_global_context` is, need to `#include` the header where it's defined?

Comment: also can't recall a C compiler complaining about "incomplete class type", are you compiling as C++?

Answer (score 2):

In `age_global_graph.h` we have:

```
typedef struct GRAPH_global_context GRAPH_global_context;
```

This is a forward declaration of the `struct`.

So, it's an incomplete type. It's perfectly okay to pass around *pointers* to it.

But, from this declaration, we *can't* dereference such pointers [because we don't actually know what's inside it].

I guess this is Apache's attempt to make the struct an "opaque" object where we just pass around [typed] pointers.

---

The actual `struct` definition is in `age_global_graph.c`:

```
typedef struct GRAPH_global_context
{
    char *graph_name;              /* graph name */
    Oid graph_oid;                 /* graph oid for searching */
    HTAB *vertex_hashtable;        /* hashtable to hold vertex edge lists */
    HTAB *edge_hashtable;          /* hashtable to hold edge to vertex map */
    TransactionId xmin;            /* transaction ids for this graph */
    TransactionId xmax;
    CommandId curcid;              /* currentCommandId graph was created with */
    int64 num_loaded_vertices;     /* number of loaded vertices in this graph */
    int64 num_loaded_edges;        /* number of loaded edges in this graph */
    ListGraphId *vertices;         /* vertices for vertex hashtable cleanup */
    struct GRAPH_global_context *next; /* next graph */
} GRAPH_global_context;
```

So, only functions in that file may actually utilize/dereference such pointers.

---

Some suggestions to remedy this ...

1. The simplest is to move definition from `age_global_graph.c` into `age_global_graph.h`.
   But, this has issues as there are *more* `struct` definitions that are only in the `.c` file. So, this may be more trouble than it's worth.
2. Put *your* new code into `age_global_graph.c` and rebuild. This could be a direct copy-and-paste. This is simple but can be difficult to maintain unless you have your own `git` branch.
3. Or, your new code into (e.g.) `my_age_graph_code.c` and add a single line: `#include "my_age_graph_code.c"` [or equiv] to `age_global_graph.c`
4. The easiest may be to put your code into a file (e.g.) `mycode.c`. Then, at the top add `#include "age_global_graph.c"`. Then, you only need to compile `mycode.c` (i.e. do *not* compile `age_global_graph.c` separately). No changes to the standard functions is required.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Thanks for answering @Craig_Estey! I tried it with the second suggestion you gave, it seems that the error is gone now, but I've got another one. This software (Apache AGE) is a postgres extension and I need to compile it with the `make` command like `make PG_CONFIG = directory/to/bin/pg_config install`. It compiles it fine, but when executing the CREATE EXTENSION age; command on postgres it throws an error: `could not find function "age_create_barabasi_albert_graph" in file "/.../postgresql-11.18/lib/age.so`. –
> Matheus Farias

A bit of a guess ...

Plugins/extensions for just about any pluggable architecture (e.g. Adobe photoshop, Firefox, etc.) need to *tell* the arch about the extension functions.

Just building the `.so` with the function usually isn't enough. The extension (e.g. `.so`) has to "register" the callback functions.

Given:

```
void
foo(void)
{
    ...
}
```

This can be a few ways ...

1. The `.so` *init* function can call (e.g.) `register_my_function("foo",foo);`
2. A `cpp` macro can designate the callable functions (e.g.) `DECLARE_MY_FUNCTION(foo)`

It appears that `postgres` uses the second method.

With a quick check of the `age` source for some already existing callback functions that work, I found a few in `graph_generation.c`. I'd study that file (and others) to provide a model for how to implement your function(s).

One of the functions is: `create_complete_graph`.

Just above the function definition, we have:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(create_complete_graph);
```

It appears that is the *only* extra syntax that provides any sort of function registration.

Note that the signature of such a function is:

```
Datum create_complete_graph(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
```

And, the function uses plenty of `PG_*` macros.

The `PG_*` macros seem to be coming from `postgres` itself rather than the given extension. So, I'd look at the `postgres` extension HOWTO documentation.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Craig_Estey! I tried it with the second suggestion you gave, it seems that the error is gone now, but I've got another one. This software (Apache AGE) is a postgres extension and I need to compile it with the `make` command like `make PG_CONFIG = directory/to/bin/pg_config install`. It compiles it fine, but when executing the `CREATE EXTENSION age;` command on postgres it throws an error: `could not find function "age_create_barabasi_albert_graph" in file "/.../postgresql-11.18/lib/age.so`.